# Can not install AzureStor on Azure DSVM as it will not detect Rtools

Tags: r, azure, azure-blob-storage, rtools, azure-dsvm

I am trying to install AzureStor in order to access Azure storage blobs from an Azure DSVM running RStudio. AzureStor needs Rtools, however I have not been able to install a working version of Rtools that RStudio can connect to. I have tried 2 install methods:
a) Downloading the latest version of Rtools and using the Rtools35.exe to install. Numerous times and ensuring that C:/Rtools/bin is at the top of the PATH list.
b) installing "installr" then running install.Rtools()

Both result in the following error:

Error: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/Microsoft/ML Server/R_SERVER/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' had status 127

This is what the path looks like following method (a):

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\ML Server\\R_SERVER\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.0\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.0\\libnvvp;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft MPI\\Bin\\;C:\\JuliaPro_v0.6.4.1\\Julia-0.6.4\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\wbin;C:\\Anaconda;C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v9.0\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v9.0\\libnvvp;C:\\windows\\system32;C:\\windows;C:\\windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\NVIDIA\\cuda\\;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVSMI\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Zulu\\zulu-8\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\hadoop\\bin;C:\\dsvm\\tools\\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Graphviz2.38\\bin;C:\\dsvm\\tools\\xgboost\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\VowpalWabbit\\;C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin;c:\\dsvm\\tools\\DataMovement\\ADL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\AzCopy;c:\\dsvm\\tools\\DataMovement\\DocumentDB\\;C:\\Program Files\\Pandoc\\;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\ML Server\\R_SERVER\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio\\;C:\\Users\\azureuser\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\azureuser\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program Files\\Docker;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\Nsight Compute 2019.3.0\\;C:\\Users\\TBFAdmin\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;"
```

This is what the path looks like following method (b):

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\ML Server\\R_SERVER\\bin\\x64;C:\\Rtools\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.0\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v10.0\\libnvvp;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft MPI\\Bin\\;C:\\JuliaPro_v0.6.4.1\\Julia-0.6.4\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\wbin;C:\\Anaconda;C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin;C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v9.0\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v9.0\\libnvvp;C:\\windows\\system32;C:\\windows;C:\\windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\NVIDIA\\cuda\\;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVSMI\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Zulu\\zulu-8\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\hadoop\\bin;C:\\dsvm\\tools\\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Graphviz2.38\\bin;C:\\dsvm\\tools\\xgboost\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\VowpalWabbit\\;C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin;c:\\dsvm\\tools\\DataMovement\\ADL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\AzCopy;c:\\dsvm\\tools\\DataMovement\\DocumentDB\\;C:\\Program Files\\Pandoc\\;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\ML Server\\R_SERVER\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio\\;C:\\Users\\azureuser\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\azureuser\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program Files\\Docker;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\Nsight Compute 2019.3.0\\;C:\\Users\\TBFAdmin\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;"
```

I can not force the Rtools directory into first place on the path list which I think is causing the problem. Has anyone successfully installed Rtools on an Azure DSVM? Or AzureStor? Help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with Microsoft R, Microsoft CRAN and using Azure DSVM. I resolved the AzurStor issue but unfortunately without solving the Rtools problem. I successfully installed AzureStor on Azure DSVM by installing from Github using the following install order.

```
    devtools::install_github("Azure/AzureAuth")
    devtools::install_github("Azure/AzureGraph")
    devtools::install_github("Azure/AzureRMR")
    devtools::install_github("Azure/AzureStor")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the latest DSVM Windows 2019, in that we have Rtools and R Open instead of MRO in windows 2016 which you are currently using it seems.